# How to Display CPT Meta on Front End through Query

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am working with two custom post types on my site: **Team** and **League**. I am creating a page template for the CPT League that will display meta from all of the 'Team' posts for team with a meta value matching the name of the League post type. The query will look through CPT 'team' for the meta value 'team_league'. The value in 'team_league' will match one of the post IDs for the 'league' type. I would then like to print each matching 'team', along with some meta from the team post, on the 'league' page.

I can successfully do this if I print a simple  with just the name of the posts found in the query. The example below successfully queries and prints the post name of each 'team' with a meta value matching the 'league' title. However, I need something far more complicated. I want to pull meta from the 'team' post and print a table containing names from the 'team' CPT.

**Working, Simplified Query:**

```
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
```

**Desired Query, Currently Doesn't Work:**

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: League Layout
Template Post Type: league
*/

$leaguename = get_the_ID();

$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'team_league',
    'meta_value' => $leaguename,
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();

    //Get the team data
    $post_status = get_post_status();
    $team_name = get_the_title();
    $captain_id = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'captain_user_id', true);
    $team_captain = get_user_by( 'ID', $captain_id );
    $team_league = get_post(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'team_league', true));
    $team_players = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'team_players_emails', true);
    $team_paid = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'current_paid_amount', true);
    $team_fee = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'payment_product_price', true);
    $team_balance = round( $team_fee - $team_paid , 2);

   echo '<p>Team Captain: <b>' . $team_captain->first_name . ' ' . $team_captain->last_name; . '</b></p>';
   echo '<p>Team Balance: <b>$' . $team_balance; . '</b></p>';
   echo '<table>';
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<th>Team Roster</th>';
   echo '</tr>';

   $users_confirmed = 0;
    foreach ($team_players as $team_player) { 
        $user = get_user_by( 'email', $team_player['email'] );
        if( $user ){
            if( !$user->first_name && !$user->last_name ){
                continue;
            }
            echo sprintf( "<tr><td>%s</td></tr>", $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name );
            $users_confirmed++;
        }
    }
    if( 0 == $users_confirmed ){
        echo sprintf( "<tr><td>%s</td></tr>", "No confirmed players for this team" );
    }
    echo '</table>';  
  }
} 

else {
  echo '<p>No Teams in this league</p>';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, the following solution works to achieve what I was aiming for above. The main change is to the args, where I had to include custom post status for my CPTs:

```
$leagueid = get_the_ID();

$args = array(
  'post_type'      => 'team',
  'posts_per_page' => - 1,
  'post_status' => array( 'mssl-completed', 'mssl-pending', 'publish' ),
  'meta_query' => array(
     array(
        'key'   => 'team_league',
        'value' => "$leagueid",
     ),
   ),
 );
```

From here I was able to write the information pulled from the post meta to my custom page template.

Answer (score 1):

For your Query Args.  Try something like this:

```
$args = array (
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'  => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
           array(
            'key'     => 'team_league',
            'value'   => $leaguename,
           ),
    ),
);
```

I don't think `'post_status' => 'any'` works.  This also uses the proper meta query format.

Comment: I updated my query args with your suggestion here, as well as adding in specific post statuses for my CPT.

Comment: If my suggestion basically works, you could up vote it ;)